# How to update view in angular, when database has changed?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Ive got a SPA using angular and 2 databases in firebase.
So theres a  control (with 2 options) where i'd like choose database to get data. For example first option means 1st database, second option means 2nd one.
The question is: "how to update view in angular, when database has changed".

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="level" ng-options="lvl in lvls"></select>
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

in controller

```
var levelString = "https://amber-inferno-9289.firebaseio.com/" + $scope.level + "/";

$scope.dictionary = new Firebase(levelString);
$scope.dictionary.on('value', function(snapshot){
    $scope.data = snapshot.val();
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Can you please to reword it? **So there is a select control where id like chose database to get data.**

Comment: See the code here https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/beyond-angularfire.html#section-overview Firebase updates happen outside of Angular's scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to do is use the `ng-change` directive on your `select` and refactor your dictionary set up logic into a function that is called on select change.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="level" ng-options="lvl for lvl in lvls" ng-change="setUpDictionary(level)"></select>
```

Then in your controller, create the `setUpDictionary` function to set `$scope.dictionary` to a new Firebase pointing at a different url etc.

I think this is what you're looking for based on what I could make from your question.

Hope it helps you out!